# The common network topologies in Web applications

Tags: web-applications, topology

If I want to setup a web application, what network topologies can I choice?
Maybe the most common topology is tree-like with a load-balancer in the front and all the servers share one database. I think there must be a lot of alternatives with different properties to suit different application scenarios.

So, what are the most common architectures int web applications?

Comment: This is a very open-ended question, but you may want to read up about content distribution networks (CDNs) as well as distributed databases.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is too broad, it really depends on what do you want to do, how much traffic do you want to support, etc.

Anyway, here is one possible example of deployment that handles microservices developed with Spring Boot by using Netflix Open Source components:

https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-at-a-glance#high-level-architecture

However, this is just one possiblity out of millions.